# How to rebase to master instead of git pull origin master?

Tags: git

I have a old branch `foo`, and wanna make it up to the latest `master`.

If I execute `$ git rebase origin master` on the `foo` branch,
somewhy the changes made in `foo` branch disappears and `foo` gets just same as the `HEAD` of `master`.

Why does this happen?
And How to rebase my `foo` branch to the master?

Here is my `git reflog`. `foo` is equal to `komoto/crop_image`.

```
fd8d9c1d (HEAD -> komoto/crop_image, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) HEAD@{0}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/komoto/crop_image
fd8d9c1d (HEAD -> komoto/crop_image, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) HEAD@{1}: rebase: checkout master
92284980 (tag: beta-test, origin/komoto/crop_image) HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from master to komoto/crop_image
```

Comment: `git rebase master` ends up with the same result.

Comment: It is fast forward, there is no conflict.

Answer (score 3):

Beware: `git rebase origin master` *means* `git checkout master; git rebase origin` (and then return to the original branch).  That's why your reflog shows:

```
HEAD@{1}: rebase: checkout master
```

(and then `HEAD@{0}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/komoto/crop_image`: obviously you were on `komoto/crop_image` when you started).

#### What you did actually run

When you write `origin` by itself *in this positional argument*, your Git follows the six-step process outlined in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  Step 6 reads:

> 6. otherwise, *refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD* if it exists.

So if `git rev-parse origin/HEAD` succeeds (and the five preceding steps fail), the sequence of commands:

```
git checkout master
git rebase origin
```

is equivalent to the sequence:

```
git checkout master
git rebase origin/master
```

If there are no commits on your `master` that are not already reachable from `origin/master`, this does nothing.  For a good introduction to reachability, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

#### What you should have run

> I have a old branch `foo`, and wanna make it up to the latest `master`.

In general, I prefer to do this as:

```
git checkout foo
git rebase master
```

but you can—because of the shortcut that I think people should avoid (it has bad failure modes in older versions of Git)—run:

```
git rebase master foo
```

Remember that rebase works by *copying* commits, so this will first enumerate all non-merge commits reachable from `foo` that are not reachable from `master`, in a topologically-sorted order,<sup>1</sup> saving their hash IDs somewhere.<sup>2</sup>  It will then use the equivalent of `git cherry-pick`<sup>3</sup> to *copy* each such commit, with the copy landing after the previously-copied commit.  The first-copied commit lands right after the tip of `master`:

```
...--A--B--C--...--N--O   <-- master
         \
          G--H--I   <-- foo
```

becomes:

```
                        G'-H'-I'  <-- foo
                       /
...--A--B--C--...--N--O   <-- master
         \
          G--H--I   [abandoned, but still findable as foo@{1}]
```

where `G'-H'-I'` is the sequence of cherry-picked, i.e., copied, commits that correspond to the original commits `G-H-I`.

---

<sup>1</sup>For a simple chain of commits with no branching and merging, the only correct topological sort is: *in order from first to last*.  If there are branch-and-merge sequences in the chain of commits you are rebasing, rebase picks *some* valid topological sort, linearizing the commits in the process and omitting merge commits.  This is actually sometimes a good idea and what you want, but more often, it's not.  Git is growing a new kind of rebase that will be able to handle this better; currently there is an option called `--preserve-merges` that attempts to do the job, but is not really adequate and should be avoided except in emergencies.

<sup>2</sup>This *somewhere* is literally *in the file full of `pick` directives* when you use `git rebase -i`.  Each `pick hash` directive tells Git to do a cherry-pick of that particular commit, listing its true name: its hash ID.  for some other kinds of rebases, the IDs are not as easily visible—but they are still saved somewhere, with the ability to *stop* the copying process when a copy step fails, then *resume* from the point where it stopped after you have manually fixed things up.

<sup>3</sup>An interactive rebase, or a rebase run with `-m` or `-s` flags, literally uses `git cherry-pick`.  All rebases probably should default to this, but currently, *non*-interactive rebases that *do not* use `-m` or `-s` use an older method that combines `git format-patch` with `git am --3way`.  See also [What is the difference between git cherry-pick and git format-patch | git am?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52119937/1256452)